# Connecting to WiFi on ESP32 using credentials from SD card

Tags: wifi, sd-card, esp32

I'd like to use an SD card to provide the login credentials to an ESP32. I've already got the ESP32 reading the relative data from the SD card and storing it as a char array on the ESP, but when I use those arrays in the WiFi.begin function it never connects.

Is this something to do with the way arrays work or am I doing something else wrong?

Respective code:

```cpp
if (dataFile) {
Serial.println("File is available");
while (dataFile.available()) {
  byte currbyte = dataFile.read();
  if (currbyte == 58) {
    reading = 1;    //Begin reading data
    i = 0;
  }
  while (reading == 1 and s == 0) {
    byte currbyte = dataFile.read();
    //Serial.print(currbyte);
    //Serial.println(char(currbyte));
    if (currbyte == 13) {
      s = 1;
      reading = 0 ;
    }
    ssid[i] = char(currbyte);
    i++;
    //Serial.println(ssid);
  }
  while (reading == 1 and s == 1) {
    byte currbyte = dataFile.read();
    //Serial.print(currbyte);
    //Serial.println(char(currbyte));
    if (currbyte == 13) {
      s = 2;
      reading = 0 ;
    }
    password[i] = char(currbyte);
    i++;
    //Serial.println(password);
  }
}
dataFile.close();
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED and count < 20) {
Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
delay(1000);
count++;}
```

Comment: Hi I've got the data of the SD card without issues, howeverI can't connect to wifi with that data stored as arrays

Comment: Alright, well I know that the code works if I manually enter the SSID and Password. A serial print of the arrays shows that they visually appear to be correct, and are being called correctly for the function

Comment: that makes it clear ... one way to debug this issue is to write the data back to the SD card and examine the result (i am assuming that you used a mac or a pc to write the data to the SD card) .... perhaps use a separate filename for each data field .... also, update your question with the info in your last comment

Comment: Writing the arrays for the SSID and password to a file on the SD card returns the correct results. So like I asked, is this something to do with arrays or is it something else I'm doing?

Comment: do not write an array to the SD card ... write the content of the array .... the SSID and password strings ... check that there are no hidden characters in the strings

Comment: I used 
dataFile.println(ssid);
dataFile.println(password);
Which when I checked the file on my computer afterwards showed the exact correct string of ASCII characters

Comment: you add the '\13' to the SSID and password string instead of the terminating zero

Comment: Where exactly do I add that? In my wifi.begin or when I finish reading the SSID from the SD card?

Comment: `ssid[i] = char(currbyte);` runs for  13 too

Answer (score 1):

you add the '\13' to the SSID and password string instead of the terminating zero, because `ssid[i] = char(currbyte);` runs for 13 too

use readBytesUntil()

```
  char ssid[33];
  int l = file.readBytesUntil('\n', ssid, sizeof(ssid));
  if (l > 0 && ssid[l-1] == '\r') {
    l--;
  }
  ssid[l] = 0;
```